# Sort data frame column by factor

Tags: r, sorting, r-factor

Supose I have a data frame with 3 columns (`name`, `y`, `sex`) where `name` is character, `y` is a numeric value and `sex` is a factor.

```
sex<-c("M","M","F","M","F","M","M","M","F")
x<-c("MARK","TOM","SUSAN","LARRY","EMMA","LEONARD","TIM","MATT","VIOLET")
name<-as.character(x)
y<-rnorm(9,8,1)
score<-data.frame(x,y,sex)
score
     name      y     sex
1    MARK  6.767086   M
2     TOM  7.613928   M
3   SUSAN  7.447405   F
4   LARRY  8.040069   M
5    EMMA  8.306875   F
6 LEONARD  8.697268   M
7     TIM 10.385221   M
8    MATT  7.497702   M
9  VIOLET 10.177969   F
```

If I wanted to order it by `y` I would use:

```
score[order(score$y),]
        x         y sex
1    MARK  6.767086   M
3   SUSAN  7.447405   F
8    MATT  7.497702   M
2     TOM  7.613928   M
4   LARRY  8.040069   M
5    EMMA  8.306875   F
6 LEONARD  8.697268   M
9  VIOLET 10.177969   F
7     TIM 10.385221   M
```

So far, so good... The names keep the correct score BUT how could I reorder it to have M and F levels not mixed. I need to order and at the same time keep factor levels separated.

Finally I would like to take a step further to involve character, the example doesn't help, but what if there were tied `y` values and I would have to order again within factor (e.g. TIM and TOM got 8.4 and I have to assign alphabetical order).

I was thinking about by function but it creates a list and doesn't help really. I think there must be some function like it to apply on data frames and get data frames as return.

TO MAKE CLEAR THE POINT:

```
sep<-split(score,score$sex)
sep$M<-sep$M[order(sep$M[,2]),]
sep$M
x         y sex
1    MARK  6.767086   M
8    MATT  7.497702   M
2     TOM  7.613928   M
4   LARRY  8.040069   M
6 LEONARD  8.697268   M
7     TIM 10.385221   M

sep$F<-sep$F[order(sep$F[,2]),]
sep$F
x         y sex
3  SUSAN  7.447405   F
5   EMMA  8.306875   F
9 VIOLET 10.177969   F

merged<-rbind(sep$M,sep$F)
merged
x         y sex
1    MARK  6.767086   M
8    MATT  7.497702   M
2     TOM  7.613928   M
4   LARRY  8.040069   M
6 LEONARD  8.697268   M
7     TIM 10.385221   M
3   SUSAN  7.447405   F
5    EMMA  8.306875   F
9  VIOLET 10.177969   F
```

I know how to do that if I have 2 or 3 factors. But what if I had serious levels of factors, say 20, should I write a `for` loop?

Comment: Are you just wanting to order by multiple variables like: `score[order(score$y,score$sex,score$x),]`?

Comment: @thelatemail, sounds more like `order(score$sex, score$y, score$x)` perhaps instead of what you proposed.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - probably - and you can chop that down like `with(score,score[order(sex, y, x),])`

Comment: I should have read your comment @thelate (or you should have posted an answer).  If you post this as an answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`order` takes multiple arguments, and it does just what you want:

```
with(score, score[order(sex, y, x),])
##         x        y sex
## 3   SUSAN 6.636370   F
## 5    EMMA 6.873445   F
## 9  VIOLET 8.539329   F
## 6 LEONARD 6.082038   M
## 2     TOM 7.812380   M
## 8    MATT 8.248374   M
## 4   LARRY 8.424665   M
## 7     TIM 8.754023   M
## 1    MARK 8.956372   M
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a summary of all methods mentioned in other answers/comments (to serve future searchers). I've added a data.table way of sorting.

```
# Base R
do.call(rbind, by(score, score$sex, function(x) x[order(x$y),]))
with(score, score[order(sex, y, x),])
score[order(score$sex,score$x),]

# Using plyr
arrange(score, sex,y)
ddply(score, c('sex', 'y'))

# Using `data.table`
library("data.table")
score_dt <- setDT(score)

# setting a key works sorts the data.table
setkey(score_dt,sex,x)
print(score_dt)
```

[Here is Another question that deals with the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

> I think there must be some function like it to apply on data frames
>   and get data frames as return

Yes there is:

```
library(plyr)

ddply(score, c('y', 'sex'))
```

Comment: The question would be, why use `plyr` for a simple order operation?

Comment: @thelatemail, You could if you used `plyr::arrange`. i.e. `arrange(score, sex,y)`.

Comment: I've just learnt from a mistake a great use of arrange. If you call arrange(score,sex,y) it works like you said but if you call arrange(score,y,sex) it gives you a dataframe with the minimum value of every factor. That is terrific! (sorry I'm new to R)

Comment: is it "plyr" or "dplyr"?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're trying to order by score within the males and females and return a combined data frame of sorted males and sorted females.

You are right that `by(score, score$sex, function(x) x[order(x$y),])` returns a list of sorted data frames, one for male and one for female. You can use `do.call` with the `rbind` function to combine these data frames into a single final data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, by(score, score$sex, function(x) x[order(x$y),]))
#           x         y sex
# F.5    EMMA  7.526866   F
# F.9  VIOLET  8.182407   F
# F.3   SUSAN  9.677511   F
# M.4   LARRY  6.929395   M
# M.8    MATT  7.970015   M
# M.7     TIM  8.297137   M
# M.6 LEONARD  8.845588   M
# M.2     TOM  9.035948   M
# M.1    MARK 10.082314   M
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the person asked how to sort it by the orders in the case of say 20.

> I know how to do that if I have 2 or 3 factors. But what if I had
> serious levels of factors, say 20, should I write a for loop?

I have one where there are 9 orders with various counts.

```
stage_name               count
  <ord>                    <int>
1 Closed Lost                957
2 Closed Won                1413
3 Evaluation                1773
4 Meeting Scheduled         4104
5 Nurture                   1222
6 Opportunity Disqualified   805
7 Order Submitted           1673
8 Qualifying                5138
9 Quoted                    4976
```

In this case you can see that it is displayed using alphabetical order of `stage_name`, but `stage_name` is actually an ordered factor that has a very different order.

This code orders the factor is a much different order:

```
# Make categoricals ----
check_stage$stage_name = ordered(check_stage$stage_name, levels=c(
    'Opportunity Disqualified', 
    'Qualifying',
    'Evaluation',
    'Meeting Scheduled',
    'Quoted',
    'Order Submitted',
    'Closed Won',
    'Closed Lost',
    'Nurture'))
```

Now we can just apply the factor as the method of ordering this is a `dplyr` function, but you might need `forcats` too.  I have both libraries installed:

```
check_stage <- check_stage %>% 
  arrange(factor(stage_name))
```

This now gives the output in the factor order as desired:

```
    check_stage

# A tibble: 9 × 2
  stage_name               count
  <ord>                    <int>
1 Opportunity Disqualified   805
2 Qualifying                5138
3 Evaluation                1773
4 Meeting Scheduled         4104
5 Quoted                    4976
6 Order Submitted           1673
7 Closed Won                1413
8 Closed Lost                957
9 Nurture                   1222
```