# Ordering categorical variables in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with three rows:

```
Date         State     Count
1994-01-05   Alabama   408
1994-01-06   Alabama   784
1994-02-08   Alabama   552
1994-01-05   Alaska    1067
1994-01-06   Alaska    36
1994-02-08   Alaska    8571
1994-01-05   Arizona   385
1994-01-06   Arizona   1845
1994-02-08   Arizona   49
```

where there are counts for the same set of dates for each of the fifty states. The dates and states are ordered as shown above.

I want to get the date into a format with four rows*:

```
Date         State     Count   mean
1994-01-05   Alabama   408     581.333
1994-01-06   Alabama   784     581.333
1994-02-08   Alabama   552     581.333
1994-01-05   Arizona   385     759.666
1994-01-06   Arizona   1845    759.666
1994-02-08   Arizona   49      759.666
1994-01-05   Alaska    1067    3224.666
1994-01-06   Alaska    36      3224.666
1994-02-08   Alaska    8571    3224.666
```

where, first, the  mean of the counts for each state is computed and inputted into the fourth column. And then, the states are reordered from smallest to largest mean.

I was able to complete the first step of computing the mean for each state, using the command:

```
plyed = ddply(dataset,.(State), transform, mean= mean(Count))
```

However, this command only computed the mean for each state, but did not reorder the states by the mean value, giving the below:

```
Date         State     Count   mean
1994-01-05   Alabama   408     581.333
1994-01-06   Alabama   784     581.333
1994-02-08   Alabama   552     581.333
1994-01-05   Alaska    1067    3224.666
1994-01-06   Alaska    36      3224.666
1994-02-08   Alaska    8571    3224.666
1994-01-05   Arizona   385     759.666
1994-01-06   Arizona   1845    759.666
1994-02-08   Arizona   49      759.666
```

I am unsure how to now reorder the states by their mean to get my desired output*. I tried the reorder command, but am getting all different and unwanted output formats. Here is one example of a command I tried with no success:

```
reorder(plyed$State, plyed$mean, order=is.ordered(plyed$State))
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297989/sort-data-frame-column-by-factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plyr::arrange`

```
arrange(ddply(df, .(State), mutate, mean = mean(Count)), mean)
##         Date   State Count    mean
## 1 1994-01-05 Alabama   408  581.33
## 2 1994-01-06 Alabama   784  581.33
## 3 1994-02-08 Alabama   552  581.33
## 4 1994-01-05 Arizona   385  759.67
## 5 1994-01-06 Arizona  1845  759.67
## 6 1994-02-08 Arizona    49  759.67
## 7 1994-01-05  Alaska  1067 3224.67
## 8 1994-01-06  Alaska    36 3224.67
## 9 1994-02-08  Alaska  8571 3224.67
```

Just for fun I'll add the `dplyr` solution

```
detach(package:plyr)
library(dplyr)
df %.%
    group_by(State) %.%
    mutate(mean = mean(Count)) %.%
    arrange(mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the order() function.  A good example can be found in the answer to this question [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r)

```
new_df <- plyed[with(plyed, order(mean)),]
```